# Isekai manga where a billionaire (scammer?) is transported in a dungeon and forced to work there

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read a manga title last year where a billionaire (scammer?) guy is transported in a dungeon and was forced to work there for a living.

I remember there was a part that he made a friend that is a lizard kin and a powerful dragon. Though the dragon is only supporting the main character because she wants food from him.

The main objective of the main character is to build a sustainable life in the dungeon, I think?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Hi Tyrone,  I did an edit to improve readability. If you've got anything you think would be useful to add, you'll want to add it to the current version

Comment: It is possible that you are mixing up 2 or 3 mangas. https://www.mangapanda.com/dungeon-nursery has essentially a scammer as the main character, https://www.readmng.com/maou-ni-natta-node-dungeon-tsukutte-jingai-musume-to-honobono-suru has a dragon helping who only wants food and the mc has to protect the dungeon, while https://www.readmng.com/maou-sama-no-machizukuri-saikyou-no-dungeon-wa-kindai-toshi also has the mc who must protect his dungeon, he wants to make his dungeon into a town.  I will say i think i read another one as you describe on one of those sites, but i cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

Meikyuu Black Company

> Ninomiya Kinja was a man that did everything to become a NEET at the age of 24, investments, hard work and everything - his efforts paid off, all because of his motto - "I don't want to work". He is really content to stay in his penthouse in those luxurious and lazy conditions until he dies. That is, until a mysterious portal sucks him into another world. This world is unlike any other, with RPG-Like aspects, including a "G" currency, a medieval fantasy feel, among other things, with a sort of twist: it is owned in part by a "Black Company", that overworks its employees up to 14 hours a day, be they humans, lizards or orcs in precarious conditions. That is his new life at "Detmolt - Demon Mineral Site". While exploring a mysterious mine, a meeting with an otherworldly girl named Rim might just tip the scales and change the pacing of his no longer ordinary life...

The main character is a NEET who did everything possible to retire as fast as possible. He actually managed to do this at 24 years old. Just when he can sit back and relax, he gets transported to a fantasy world where he becomes a mine worker. One of his co-workers is a lizard and he involves him in a lot of shady stuff in order to escape.

The dragon is Rim. She intended to eat them, but Ninomiya can bribe her off by offering her food. She then proceeds to ALWAYS want free food from him.